# Substring in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to extract a substring using the following query. I am not getting the expected result.

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(10)
SET @st1 = 'Case # 00548295'
SELECT @st1,ltrim(SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX('# ', @st1) + 1, LEN(@st1)))
```

I am getting 005 as the answer. I am trying to extract the integer values after 'Case[space]#[Space]...". My result needs to be 00548295. What is wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `@st1` as varchar(10), but then try to assign 15 characters (`'Case # 00548295'`) to it. SQL Server silently truncates the data in this case.

Simply increase the size:

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(20)
SET @st1 = 'Case # 00548295'
SELECT @st1,ltrim(SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX('# ', @st1) + 1, LEN(@st1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not give your varchar variable enough characters to hold the entire string to begin with.

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(20)
SET @st1 = 'Case # 00548295'
SELECT @st1,ltrim(SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX('# ', @st1) + 1, LEN(@st1)))

-------------------- --------------------
Case # 00548295      00548295

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, you need to increase your variable size.  As for your query, instead of substringing out the numbers, you can simply get rid of 'Case # '

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(20)
SET @st1 = 'Case # 00548295'
SELECT @st1, REPLACE(@st1, 'Case # ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string value is `varchar(10)` which is at most 10 characters long.  If you select out `@st1`, you will see it is truncated to 10 characters: 'Case # 005'.  You will need to declare this as at least a `varchar(15)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the varchar(15) issue already identified, you can also avoid the "ltrim" and parameterize the delimiter, as shown here:

```
DECLARE @st1 varchar(15)
declare @delimiter nvarchar(2) = '# ';
declare @delim_len int = DATALENGTH (@delimiter) / 2;
SET @st1 = 'Case # 00548295'
SELECT @st1, SUBSTRING(@st1, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @st1) + @delim_len, LEN(@st1))
```

Or take it one step further, and make it into a SQL Function:

```
if object_id('UFN_STRINGAFTER') is not null
begin
  drop function UFN_STRINGAFTER;
end
go


create function dbo.UFN_STRINGAFTER
(
  @input nvarchar(max)
 ,@delimiter nvarchar(max) = '# '
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @delim_len int = DATALENGTH (@delimiter) / 2;
  return SUBSTRING(@input, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input) + @delim_len, LEN(@input));
end;
go

select dbo.UFN_STRINGAFTER('Case # 00548295',default);
```